# Pseudo random number generation on the gpu

Tags: random, gpu, compute-shader

Using a C# script in the Unity3D game engine to control a HLSL compute shader, I'm trying to generate pseudo random numbers on the GPU and store them in a Texture2D. Following along with
[GPU Gems 3 Hybrid Tausworthe method](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch37.html)
and another thread [Pseudo Random Number Generation on the GPU](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337782/pseudo-random-number-generation-on-the-gpu#answers-header), I've come across an issue.

#### The problem:

the resulting texture appears to be one solid color. If I run the shader multiple times, I get a different solid color texture result every time, but the entire texture is the one color.

#### Compute shader code

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> result; // 256 resolution texture to write to
uint4 seed;  //four uniform random numbers generated on the CPU in a C# script

struct RandomResult
{
    uint4 state;
    float value;
};

uint TausStep(uint z, int S1, int S2, int S3, uint M)
{
    uint b = (((z << S1) ^ z) >> S2);
    return ((z & M) << S3) ^ b;
}
uint LCGStep(uint z, uint A, uint C)
{
    return A * z + C;
}
RandomResult HybridTaus(uint4 state)
{
    state.x = TausStep(state.x, 13, 19, 12, 4294967294);
    state.y = TausStep(state.y, 2, 25, 4, 4294967288);
    state.z = TausStep(state.z, 3, 11, 17, 4294967280);
    state.w = LCGStep(state.w, 1664525, 1013904223);

    RandomResult rand;
    rand.state = state;
    rand.value = 2.3283064365387e-10 * (state.x ^ state.y ^ state.z ^ state.w);

    return rand;
}

[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id)
{
    result[id.xy] = HybridTaus(seed).value;
}
```

Do I need to save the state on the gpu? If so, how would I do that? Do I need to deallocate the memory afterwards?

I tried to assign the result of the HybridTaus() function to `seed` in hopes that it would use the new value in the following HybridTaus(seed) call to see if that would make a difference. I also tried to add unique arbitrary numbers based on the thread id, which is the `id` parameter. This gave some improved results, but I suspect the randomness is only as good as I can make it, coming from maths performed on the thread ids and not effectively from the random number generator.

```
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id)
{
    //first thing I tried
    //RandomResult rand = HybridTaus(seed);
    //seed = rand.state;  // re-assign seed with the new state

    //result[id.xy] = rand.value;

    //second thing I tried
    RandResult rand = HybridTaus(seed * uint4(id.x*id.y*id.x*id.y,
                                              id.x*id.y/id.x*id.y, 
                                              id.x*id.y+id.x*id.y,
                                              id.x*id.y-id.x*id.y));
    result[id.xy] = rand.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know about the algo you posted but i found [this](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/quick-and-easy-gpu-random-numbers-in-d3d11/) simple algorithm online for generating random numbers on the gpu. Here `seed` is a 32 bit `uint`.

```
uint wang_hash(uint seed)
{
    seed = (seed ^ 61) ^ (seed >> 16);
    seed *= 9;
    seed = seed ^ (seed >> 4);
    seed *= 0x27d4eb2d;
    seed = seed ^ (seed >> 15);
    return seed;
}
```

Now in most cases this is sufficient, you can pass your compute shader's Local invocation ID as that is unique and get a random number per thread or per invocation. However if you need multiple random numbers per invocation (for example you have a loop or a nested loop) this wasn't working as the `seed` remains the same. So i messed the function a little bit and came up with this

```
uint wang_hash(uint seed)
{
    seed = seed + 76.897898 * 48.789789 *  cos(x) * sin(y) * 20.79797
    seed = (seed ^ 61) ^ (seed >> 16);
    seed *= 9;
    seed = seed ^ (seed >> 4);
    seed *= 0x27d4eb2d;
    seed = seed ^ (seed >> 15);
    return seed;
}
```

Here `x` and `y` are my nested for loops variables. And this works for me. Now you can get multiple random numbers per invocation.

In your case however, I don't think you need the latter one. If I understood correct you just need to store a random number for every texel so you can try the first one and use the unique local invocation ID to get random numbers for every texel value.